# Как в функции вырезать и передать поля?

Tags: php, парсер, api

```
   function str_parse($str) {
        preg_match_all('~\b89\d{9}\b|#[^#\s]+~', $str, $arr);
        $text_clean = preg_replace('~\b89\d{9}\b\.?|#[^#\s]+~', '', $str);
        $hashtag = $arr[0][1] ?? false;
        $phone = $arr[0][0] ?? false;
        return compact('text_clean', 'phone', 'hashtag');
    }
```

Всем доброго времени суток. У меня два вопроса. Есть функция, которая принимает переменную с текстом, вырезает из него телефон и хэштег.

1. Как из этого текста скопировать (не вырезать) первую строку до точки и выдать его в переменной $title?
2. Как вырезать цену (только цифры) слово "Цена:" постоянная. 
   если цены нет то выдать в переменную $price пустое поле.

Пример текста:

> Звонить с 10 до 18 в будние дни. Оплата ежедневная, до 50% (после 15
>   000) Удаленная отчетность. График 5/2, 6/1 , плавающие выходные.
>   Стабильный поток заказов,2-3 в день. Цена: 10000р 89999999999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день.
Для забора первого предложения до точки можно использовать функцию explode

```html
str = 'Тестовая строка. Тест';
echo  explode(".", $str)[0];
```

по второму вопросу preg_match и регулярка

```html
$str = 'Звонить с 10 до 18 в будние дни. Оплата ежедневная, до 50% (после 15 000) Удаленная отчетность. График 5/2, 6/1 , плавающие выходные. Стабильный поток заказов,2-3 в день. Цена: 10000р 89999999999';

preg_match('/Цена:(.*)р/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

посмотрите вывод этого кода. Ну и дальше работайте с этим массивом, проводите нужные проверки.

> http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php